# How to know if a Variable Binding represents a local variable, in Eclipse JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt, local-variables

I've noticed `eclipse.jdt.core.dom` variable bindings (`IVariableBinding`) offer boolean methods to check if they are representing a **field**, **Enum constant** or **parameter** ( `isEnumConstant()`, `isField()` and `isParameter()` ).

How can I know if it represents a local variable? Is it safe to assume that if a `IVariableBinding` is not one of the former three it will ALWAYS be a local variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the Eclipse Forums (thanks to Deepak Azad): **YES**, it will always be a local variable, as I suspected.